# Finding the largest set where a complex function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am considering the function
$$
f(z) = \frac{e^z}{\sin z - \cos z}.
$$

So I solved for $\sin z - \cos z = 0$ and got $\pi/4$. But why is it $\pi/4 + k\pi$ and not $\pi/4 + k2\pi$ for the part of the complex plane where this function is not analytic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

$$\sin z -\cos z=0\Longleftrightarrow \tan z = 1\Longrightarrow z=\frac{\pi}{4}+k\pi\,\,,\,k\in\Bbb Z$$

as the period of the tangent function is $\,\pi\,$ , not $\,2\pi\,$

Comment: Ohhh ok, thanks!

Comment: What about for this function: f(z) = Log ((2-iz)^2)

So I solved for 2-iz = 0 and got z =/= -2i

But when I solve for (2-iz)^2 = 0 i get z=/= 2i

I was wondering which way should be the correct approach for this question?

Comment: Please do post a new question in a new thread, so that all can see it...and don't forget to upvote answers that help you.